# Dynamic Widget creation based of configparser file

Tags: python, dynamic, tkinter

I am trying a piece of python based tkinter code with following objective:
(Please go through the objective, then I will take an example to explain what exactly i require and then in the end will post the script I have written)

1. Reads from a config file, which is implemented using configparser module.
2. Based on options read from this file it automatically generates widget.
3. These widgets are restricted to only labels and entry box as of now.
4. Every entry box is associated with a variable. It is hence needed to generate a variable
   automatically whenever a entry box is declared.
5. Now when the user enters any value in the entry box, and presses calculate button a list is
   generated with combination of values entered by user( in a specific format).

Example:
Let the configparser file has following content:

> [widget]
>
> label = ani_label,sham_label
>
> entry = ani,sham

The list generated for this case will be like this:

> out_list = ['-ani','< ani >','-sham','< sham >']

## < ani > means value stored in ani variable

And below is the code that i have tried.

```
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import Tk
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import ConfigParser
import sys
############ Initialize ###############################
parser_read = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
parser_read.read('option_read.config')
config_list = {}
config_list['label'] = parser_read.get('widget','label').split(',')
config_list['entry'] = parser_read.get('widget','entry').split(',')


######
def calculate():
    #Will include the list generation part
    pass


#######
root = Tk()
root.title("NRUNTEST GUI VERSION 1")
#
menuframe = ttk.Frame(root)
menuframe.grid(column=0,row=0)
menuframe.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
menuframe.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
#
mainframe_label = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe_label.grid(column=1,row=0)
mainframe_label.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
mainframe_label.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
#
mainframe_entry = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe_entry.grid(column=2,row=0)
mainframe_entry.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
mainframe_entry.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)


#
general_label= Label(menuframe,text="Please Enter the Values Below").grid(column=1,row=0,sticky=(E))
compiler_label= ttk.Label(menuframe,text="Compiler")
compiler_label.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=W)
#
calculate_button = ttk.Button(menuframe, text="Calculate", command=calculate).grid(column=1,row=2,sticky=(W,E))
#Automatic Widget declaration ###
for x in config_list['label']:
    x = ttk.Label(mainframe_label,text=x).grid()

for x in config_list['entry']:
    #print x
var = lambda: sys.stdout.write(x)
x = ttk.Entry(mainframe_entry,textvariable = x).grid()


root.mainloop()
```

The content of option_read.config is

```
[widget]
label : animesh_label,sharma
entry : animesh_entry,sharma
```

STATUS:
I can create the required widgets automatically. But I am not able to create the variables dynamically to store the entry box values.
Once the variable has been calculated, I can write the calculate function on my own.

Please advice how i can proceed.
If you have any better way to meet my requirements, please do suggest.
Also do ping me if you require any more inputs or my query is not clear.

Comment: You say you are "not able to create the variables dynamically". Why? Are you getting errors? Do you _really_ need to use variables, or do you just want to? Are you aware you don't need to use variables to get and set the contents of an entry widget.

Comment: I was actually trying to generate individual variables.Owing to my recently gained modest knowledge in python,this seemed the right way.
But my prime target is to develop a script where -declaration,layout and later the final output- is totally automated and dependent on content read from the configparser file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, IMO, is to use a dict to store the references to the dynamically created variables. You could use the label as the key. For example:

```
vars = {}
for x in config_list['entry']:
    vars[x] = StringVar()
    entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe_entry, textvariable=vars[x])
    entry.grid()
```

By the way... are you aware that if you do something like `x=ttk.Entry(...).grid(...)`, `x` does *not* contain a reference to the widget? It contains the result of the call to `grid`, which is None.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me get back to you after trying this.
Also, is there anyway I can automate the widget layout, so that by means of the configparser file, user can also decide what widget to place and where to place.